# How to hide a <li> if the Button contains "sometext" - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]
As you can see in the image, i have some kind of table, and i need to hide the entire "< div >" called table with **jQuery**, **if** the button inside the "< div >" says "**ASK**"
The thing is i know how to hide (actually i want it to disappear, which i accomplished) but the part **i can't do** is to relate the **button.ASK** to the **div.table**

code to disappear the div: `$("div.table").css("display", "none");`

code i need to modify:

```
<div class="_npuc5">
<div class="_f5wpw">
<a class="of_gvoze" href="Random_David" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;"><img class="_rewi8" src="http://es.horadeaventura.wikia.com/wiki/Archivo:AT_Icons_100x100_Jake.jpg">
</a>
<div class="_eryrc">
<div class="_2nunc">
<a class="_2g7d5w8" title="SOME TITLE HERE" href="ggggg.com/">RandomText</a>
</div>
<div class="Random_9mmn5">SOME TEXT HERE</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="_mtnzs">
<span class="LLLL"><button class="askButton">ASK</button></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if the button is inside the li, which it looks like, then you could use the parent or parents function. That's if I have understood your meaning correctly. Include the code of your list etc so we can see it properly. A picture in this case doesn't really cut it fully.

Comment: Use a row number or identity in your li values then use the same row number or identity in your table ids, then you can relate that to the correct table and hide it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, you are right, but should i delete my question now?

Comment: No, it should ask you if you accept the duplicate, and you can accept it. A duplicate is a good thing, since it adds more keywords to find the answer on.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`:contains()` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $("li:contains('ASK')").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One <button type="button">ASK</button>
    <li>One <button type="button">REPLY</button>
      <li>One <button type="button">REPLY</button>
        <li>One <button type="button">REPLY</button>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```js
$('#toggledisplay').click(function (){

  //get all the list items
  var lis = $('li');
  
  //with the filter function, I can 
  //specify custom conditions 
  //to the elements I want to do something with
  lis.filter(function (index){
    // "this" is the current li on the loop.
    //if the innertext of "this" equals "ask"
    //then yes, this is the li I want
    return $(this).text().trim() == "ASK";
  }).toggle();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>ASK</li>
  <li>nope</li>
  <li>hey</li>
</ul>

<br>

<button id="toggledisplay"> Togggle the display of "ASK" </button>
```